# Why Rails cannot add a new record to database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL. I have the next form on `/main` URL(localhost:3000/main):

```
=form_for(@car) do |b|
    .col-xs-2= b.text_field(:type, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Type")
    = b.submit('Buy', class: "btn btn-default")
```

In my Controller:

```
def main
  @car = Car.new
end

def new
  @car = Car.new
end

def create
@car = Car.new(car_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @car.save
    format.html { redirect_to @car, notice: 'Car was successfully ordered.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @car }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @car, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

where

```
def car_params
  params.require(:car).permit(:type)
end
```

I checked my code 100 times and it seems everything okay, but I cannot add a new record to my database table. Can anyone help me why it happens? What is the problem in my code?

Comment: Here we go again. Don't change your question 20 times. You invalidate answers. Post your actual code from the start, in the first revision.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev you are right! Sorry for that! That's how my code looks now!

Comment: Can you verify that if there is any kind of validations applied in model?
You can print the @car.errors in else block to verify it

Comment: show your model

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it's empty

Comment: @Doe: well, you need to learn some simple debugging tricks. Does the control hit the create action? What are the parameters? What is the result of `@car.save`? It's it's `false`, what are `@car.errors`? and so on, and so forth.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev my console gives me that: `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"sk2uLzGNSXgQN7OuYaAduFgZUyiBh6UJu/sGcMdiMJfhwbHOjeTXA2D8sOnz8xCqyJh8salA==", "car"=>{"type"=>"123"}, "commit"=>"Buy"}`

Comment: @Doe: what about the rest of the questions? :)

Comment: @Doe: how do you check that record is not created?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to save the car. Although you declare and set the object, you forgot to save it in the database.

You should do it by adding the following line:

```
@car.save
```

in the create action

Comment: ah no, sorry. It's my mistake on filling the code inside of question. So I have save method in my code. I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

A few things missing your create method.  Need to add ".new" where the car variable is being set, and then also ".save" where the if statement is, I believe that should do it.

Create method should be like below

```
def create
   @car = Car.new(car_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @car.save
    format.html { redirect_to @car, notice: 'Car was successfully ordered.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @car }
else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @car, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

Comment: ah no, sorry. It's my mistake on filling the code inside of question. So I have 'new' method in my code. I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

`@car = Car(car_params)` is not correct.
You need to do `@car = Car.new(car_params)`

Comment: ah no, sorry. It's my mistake on filling the code inside of question. So I have 'new' method in my code. I updated my question. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to do is to replace this line in your create method.

```
@car = Car(car_params)
```

with this line

```
@car = Car.new(car_params)
```

Because we need to initialize the record of car with the params permitted. After that you have to call `@car.save` which will return a boolean.

So you can check it in if condition like

```
if @car.save
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: ah no, sorry. It's my mistake on filling the code inside of question. So I have 'new' method in my code. I updated my question. Sorry for that!

Comment: Can you verify that if there is any kind of validations applied in model?

Comment: You can print the @car.errors in else block to verify it.